# jQuery Masonry isn't working in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, jquery-masonry

I'm designing my Tumblr theme as grid (a two-column grid with 500px width on each post) and Masonry doesn't seem to work. The grid isn't "seamless." This is how it looks like right now: [image](http://static.tumblr.com/ls5fqgx/45Xm6i5rh/untitled.png)

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I've been at it for hours and have tried more than two dozens of suggestions like adding "display: block;" etc. Nothing works. The only change I keep getting besides this is the posts would overlap over each other, which is worse than this.

Here is my complete Tumblr workup: [[codes]](http://static.tumblr.com/ls5fqgx/9kqm6i5mv/tumblr.txt).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with firebug?

Comment: I have and use firebug but what does debugging mean? How do I do that?

Comment: Debugging is the same as unit testing, set up several different unit tests for each section or event and then run them and see when the unit test fails (And that gives you a better idea of where the error might be occurring). QUnit is a good debugger/unit tester for javascript/jquery.

Comment: Why do you call the `jquery 1.3.2` and `1.6.1` libraries? are you sure they aren't conflicting with each other?

Comment: No, they don't seem to be conflicting, but I removed the other one just to be sure.

Comment: Yes? I'm willing to try anything at this point, really.

Comment: I've updated my answer with `);` and tested it on a local server, you just had incorrect closing syntax.

Comment: With the update, the posts overlapped over each other as though their position is set on absolute. They're just in one stack like a sandwich :\

Answer (score 0):

From  what I see on your [code](https://static.tumblr.com/ls5fqgx/9kqm6i5mv/tumblr.txt) when you make a call to `masonry` on `jQuery(window).load(function(){`, you forgot to close your load call.

Based off the code you provided your `<script type="text/javascript">` has.

```
 jQuery(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.post',
  columnWidth : 520
  });
```

[image: before]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/2t02emn1.z3f.png))</sub>

Which looks fine until I saw there is no closing syntax `});` and I don't believe you ever call `jQuery.noConflict()` (it doesn't matter, it will work with `jQuery` too, but  it should look like..

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.post',
  columnWidth : 520
  });
  });
```

You can test it with `alert('hello this is a working test');`

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  alert('hello this is a working test');
  $('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.post',
  columnWidth : 520
  });
  });
```

[image: after]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/5i4xd5fe.xc4.png))</sub>

After the alert box disappears you will notice the jQuery takes effect and the `{block:Posts}{/block:Posts}` will disappear from view.

Comment: No, that didn't do anything..It's funny since I did everything Masonry said to do step-by-step and it's still not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two problems:

1. You need to move your `<div class="post"> </div>` tags inside of each post element
2. You need to close your function call on window.load

So, #1 will look something like this...

```
<div id="container">
{block:Posts}    

{block:Text}
<div class="post">
{block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}
{Body}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}
<div class="post">
<center>{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}</center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
<div class="post">
<center>{Photoset-500}</center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
<div class="post">
<span class="quote">&ldquo;{Quote}&rdquo;</span>
{block:Source}{Source}{/block:Source}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Quote}

{block:Link}
<div class="post">
<a title="" href="{URL}" class="postlink" {Target}>{Name}</a>
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Link}

{block:Audio}
<div class="post">
{AudioPlayerGrey}
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Audio}

{block:Chat}
<div class="post">
{block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">
    {block:Lines}
        <li>
            {block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}{Line}
        </li>
    {/block:Lines}            
</ul>
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Chat}

{block:Video}
<div class="post">
<center>{Video-500}</center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Video}

{block:Answer}
<div class="post">
<b>{Asker} asked:</b> {Question}
<p>{Answer}
</div><!--post-->
{/block:Answer}   

{/block:Posts}

</div><!--container-->
```

And #2 will look something like this...

```
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
           itemSelector: '.post',
           columnWidth : 520
      });
  });
```